# Is special relativity relevant to understand nuclear bombs?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, nuclear-engineering

It is often claimed that Special Relativity had a huge impact on humanity because its understand enabled the invention of the nuclear bomb. Often, the formula $E = mc^2$ is displayed in this context, as if it would explain how nuclear bombs work. I don't understand this line of reasoning.

- The key to understanding nuclear fission is understanding neutron scattering and absorption in U-235. For this, quantum mechanics is key.
- Bringing quantum mechanics and special relativity together correctly requires quantum field theory, which wasn't available in the 1940's.
- When U-236 breaks up, it emits neutrons at 2 MeV (says [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_temperature#Fast)), which is a tiny fraction of their rest mass, that is to say, far below light speed. Meaning hopefully that non-relativistic QM calculations should give basically the same answers as relativistic ones.

So it seems to me that in an alternate universe where quantum mechanics was discovered and popularised long before special relativity, people would still have invented fission chain reaction and the nuclear bomb, without knowing about special relativity.

Or, more precisely: **You don't need to understand special relativity to understand nuclear bombs. Right?**

Of course it's true that you can apply $E = mc^2$ and argue that the pieces of the bomb, collected together after the explosion, are lighter than the whole bomb before the explosion. But that's true for a TNT bomb as well. And what's more, it's an impractical thought experiment that has no significance for the development of the technology.

Comment: Using nuclear reaction Q values implies relativity. What are you really asking here?

Comment: This might be more useful as a [history-of-science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) question, as in, "in what ways did an understanding of special relativity inform the development of atomic energy?"

Comment: @JonCuster so the argument is that the Q values have to be derived via the masses of the different nuclei (before and after the fission reaction), and the energy of the neutrons could not be derived differently (experimentally somehow)?

Comment: Indeed, a full answer here would be much more involved by history than by physics. I could type up an answer of ways that special relativity plausibly could have informed the development of atomic energy, but I am not 100% clear how much of it would be true and how much would be apocryphal.

Comment: I think it's still interesting without the historical context at least from a pedagogical point of view.

Comment: you do not need quantum field theory to have conservation of energy bounds. You need special relativity to understand how mass is not conserved (mass conservation  was a law in classical physics)

Comment: Mass-energy equations apply to nuclear detonations, but not wholely..... Trinity Site where the United States detonated it's first Nuclear bomb 18.6 kiloton bomb. The amount of energy released of a 18.6 Kilotons was about 78 Terajoules; still was equivalent to the conversion of 0.9 gram of matter into energy. Which was converted to radiation and heat. The bomb used 64 kilograms of uranium has a mass energy equivalence of 5.7 Exajoules

Comment: It depends on which aspect of the bomb you want to understand, which in turn depends on which side of the bomb you are on ;-).

Comment: Your value of Q released from fission is too low.  It is in the range of 200 MeV, not 2 MeV.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's certainly relevant. Mass is very measurably non-conserved in nuclear reactions. Using special relativity allows us to determine the potential energy release of a given nuclear reaction just by directly measuring the masses of the nuclei involved and using $E=mc^2$ to convert that to an energy.

For instance, consider the reaction:

$$ \rm ^{235}U+n\to {^{140}Xe}+ {^{94}Sr}+2n $$

The masses on the left add up to about 236.05 atomic mass units, while the masses on the right add up to about 235.85 atomic mass units. Multiplying the difference by $c^2$ gives an energy of $185~\rm MeV$.

In other words, special relativity allows us to take measurements of a few hundred *masses* and to determine fission candidates that way rather than having to painstakingly attempt to experimentally determine it for every possible isotope. It also gives us a way to measure the energy release independent of having to actually precisely measure the kinetic energy of all the daughter particles (which is hard), and instead only requires us to identify the daughter isotopes and measure their masses (which is less hard).

Comment: This is the answer. The development happened very fast: only 13 years elapsed between the discovery of the neutron and the first detonation of a nuclear bomb. Much of this rapid pace may be attributed to the way the "curve of binding energy" inferred from atomic mass data informed experiments and their interpretation.

Comment: Still I'd say a better phrasing would be “SR was historically relevant for developing nuclear bombs” not “SR is relevant to understand nuclear bombs”. If somebody had just by accident discovered that ²³⁵U can act as a neutron-multiplier, then the energy output possibilities would have quickly become obvious from further experiments, and a bomb could have been designed all without using $E=mc^2$. (Though, for sure, the observed non-conservation of mass would have been a big head-scratcher and before long somebody would have noticed the proportionality of mass-loss and energy output.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout You can imagine an alternative history where nuclear bombs were discovered without knowing about special relativity if you want. It wouldn't make $E=mc^2$ any less useful for computing yields or predicting other fissile elements.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Really, as you say someone would eventually determine $E\approx mc^2$, and then they'd start using that, because it's super useful.

Comment: @Chris well, they would discover $E = m \xi$ and use that. Theorists would speculate around the curious fact that $\xi$ has dimensions of a velocity squared and $\sqrt\xi \approx c$, which the experimentalists would perhaps find intriguing but largely shrug of as “why would that matter here, the fission fragments and neutrons are going at quite different speeds, not $c$”.

Comment: @leftaroundabout "well they would discover $E=m\xi$ and *use that*." Yes. Because it's useful. Do you think it would make more sense to teach students "in the context of nuclear reactions, $E=m\xi$, and $\xi$ is exactly equal to $c^2$, but don't ask why?"

Comment: All you need is the simple formula E = mc^2 to calculate the energy that is set free. You don't need to understand relativity for that. Actually, you could have constructed a bomb, tested it, estimated the energy released, estimated the loss of mass, and get two equations E = mK, where m is the mass of the uranium involved and K some rather large constant, and another E = mK', where m is the amount of mass lost and K' an even larger constant. No relativity needed.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: First they would have figured out that the energy is proportional to the amount of uranium used, and would have believed that it is some basic property of uranium. Years later, plutonium would have been found to work in a similar way with a different plutonium specific constant. And only with two different fission reactions someone might have figured out that starting with the mass loss would give the same constant in both cases. Although nobody knows what the mass loss during a bomb explosion is, because nobody knows which percentage of material is part of the explosion.

Answer (score 15):

In Serber's book *The Los Alamos Primer*, he explains the energetics of fission bombs and asserts that the actual fission process (i.e., the impact of a neutron with a certain amount of incident energy upon a metastable nucleus, causing it to deform and neck down into two primary fission fragments which start off almost touching and then electrostatically repel one another with tremendous force and thereby accelerate to great speed) is entirely *nonrelativistic*.

(Nuclear forces enter the picture in the sense that in the uranium nucleus, the attractive nuclear force is just barely capable of holding the nucleus together against the mutual repulsion of all the protons in it, and when furnished with the right activation energy, the nucleus flies apart.)

But to calculate the *energy yield* of the fission process, one easily notes the resulting mass deficit among the primary and secondary fragments and uses Einstein's formula to equate that to a net energy release per fission.

Comment: This argument (which appears sound) begs the question whether the energy yield from nuclear fission can as well be computed -- approximately -- from an estimate of the nuclear forces vs. the electrostatic ones. After all, *every* system losing energy "loses" the corresponding  mass as well, but we rarely use relativistic physics to compute the amount of energy from the mass loss but instead simply integrate the forces over space.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The nuclear interaction has always been too complicated for that approach to be better than hand-waving. During the Manhattan Project era, mass measurements were more robust than any nuclear theory, which used mass measurements as inputs. Even today, the best measurement of the neutron mass comes from measuring the deuterium binding energy.

Answer (score 9):

"Often, the formula $E=mc^2$ is displayed in this context, as if it would explain how nuclear bombs work. I don't understand this line of reasoning."

Neither do I. $E=mc^2$ provides a neat way of *calculating* how much energy is released in nuclear fission, but to understand *why* this energy is released I need an explanation in terms of nuclear forces.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that a chain reaction can continue with a neutral particle (neutron) causing fission, and the tremendous release of energy from the decrease in rest mass from the fission reaction, were very quickly recognized.  It was then obvious that fission could quite likely be utilized for a massively powerful bomb.

"Release of energy" (from chemical reactions) was long recognized and called "energy (or enthalpy) of formation".  Calorimetry measurements were used to evaluate the energy release for chemical reactions, such as combustion.

Later, special relativity explained this energy release as a change in rest mass. So, even without special relativity the concept of a reaction releasing energy was known.  The key point for fission is how an estimate of the energy release was estimated. Fission was discovered by observing fission products (e.g. barium). Special relativity had been developed (1905) when fission was discovered (1938), so the equivalence of energy and mass was understood. Using $E = mc^2$ allowed an estimate of the tremendous amount of energy released per fission reaction (about 200 MeV) compared to a chemical reaction (about 10 eV).  I do not know if there was another way to estimate this energy release based on the early observations of fission; I do not think early experiments with fission created enough reactions to utilize calorimetry, but I could be wrong.

Comment: But do you need special relativity for that?

Comment: I think $E = mc^2$ was needed to estimate the tremendous release of energy from fission.  Please see my revised answer.

Comment: E = 1/2 mc^2 (a reasonable conjecture without knowledge of relativity) would have worked just fine as well.

Comment: Yes, I just do not know if there was a classical way to estimate the energy release without using the equivalence of mass and energy.

Answer (score 6):

in 1938 Lise Meitner was instrumental in linking the energy gained from the fission reaction to the drop in mass. As soon as this was noticed by the scientific community a number of weapons programs were started (in secret of course). The formula showed that the result was not a mistake, and that an enormous amount of energy could be tapped at a time when war in europe was looming.

While you could probably find a way to ignore $E=mc^2$ it is a very simple equation that is well recognised by the public, I think this is the main reason it gets quoted so often.

Answer (score 5):

Promoted from a comment by [Andrew](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/27732/andrew):

> I would actually take the opposite point of view. TNT releases energy in chemical bonds. In principle, there is some *tiny* amount of mass associated with the chemical bonds because of $E=mc^2$. This mass is lost in TNT. Nuclear binding energy is **much** larger than chemical binding energy, so while you can get away with saying mass is conserved with chemical reactions because you can't measure the change in mass, you cannot ignore the change in mass in nuclear reactions. (Keep in mind that since $c^2$ is huge in SI units, apparently tiny changes in mass correspond to huge amounts of energy).

Furthermore, the reply

> Indeed, nuclear Q values are no different from Q values for chemical reactions. Knowing that Q values corresponds to rest mass energy differences adds understanding, but is not needed to work out the physics of fission, which is basically non-relativistic.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question. This is a comment about an inessential comment I made in the question.

Comment: And whether you can measure something or not simply depends on the accuracy of the measurement device. There is no principle that forbids measuring the weight of the energy lost in a TNT bomb.

Comment: @Turion My point is that in principle you also need special relativity to explain the mass loss in TNT. The reason that people say you need special relativity to explain nuclear bombs and they don't say the same thing about TNT is because you actually can measure the mass loss in nuclear bombs. The energy in the explosion comes from a release of binding energy. That binding energy results in a loss of mass because of $E=mc^2$. Whether you say special relativity is "necessary" for the explanation is just semantics. There's a loss of binding energy, which translates to a loss of mass, due to SR.

Comment: But noone ever collects pieces of nuclear bombs. In particular, you don't need to do that in order to design a nuclear bombs. My question is not about whether you _can_ describe nuclear bombs with SR, but rather whether SR is _necessary_ to understand it.

Comment: @Turion If you add up the mass of the parts on the left hand side of a nuclear reaction, and the mass of the parts on the right hand side, the two numbers are different, by a measurable amount. To explain this difference, you need SR. This difference is also related to the binding energy that is released and goes into the explosion, by $E=mc^2$. I mean, maybe you *can* find a way to avoid talking about the missing mass, but whether you succeed or not the mass is still missing because of SR. I don't see the benefit to not discussing SR.

Comment: But people *do* collect the detritus of nuclear reactions. Fission was discovered when irradiation of uranium was found to produce barium, via a chemistry experiment. The energy of the reaction was computed based on precision mass data from chemistry as well. Atomic mass measurements are essential to the design of atomic bombs.

Comment: @rob Products of subcritical reactions, yes! That makes a lot of sense. Ok, if the energy can only be obtained that way then the mass measurements are essential.

Comment: @Turion said “This is a comment about an inessential comment I made in the question”. Just a hint for future questions. It is best to leave inessential comments out of your question for exactly this reason

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about relativity, a good guess would have been $E = 1/2 mc^2$ - that is the kinetic energy of a mass accelerated to the speed of light, ignoring relativity. That's half as much as the correct formula, but still plenty to give an almighty explosion and plenty to start trying to build a nuclear bomb.

And while we can determine quite precisely how much mass is lost by the fission of a single uranium atom, we don't actually have any idea about what percentage of the uranium will become part of the explosion. 30% fissioned with $E = mc^2$ or 60% fissioned with $E = 1/2 mc^2$ would give exactly the same explosion.

So I very much doubt that relativity was of any importance to building and understanding of nuclear bombs. With my alternative formula, our estimates of what percentage of uranium is part of the explosion would be off by a factor two, but it wouldn't make any difference. Only if the percentage is suspiciously high physicists would say "it's hard to imagine how we managed to make 90% of the uranium part of the fission process", or worse "we calculated that 110% of the uranium fissioned - clearly something is going on that we don't understand".